# How to pick which graphic processor to use?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, kubuntu, intel

I just changed into Kubuntu from Windows 7. Normally, I would use built-in Intel GPU instead of Nvidia for normal operations. When using graphical software or games, I would change it into Nvidia using context menu.

How can I switch between those two cards?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer for it:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2117866